# Changing the units on the x-axis in a LibreOffice Calc chart

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I've used the LibreOffice chart wizard to make a chart, and I would like the x-values to be different to the default of 1,2,3... (in this case, 500,1000,...). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by setting the "`Scale`" properties of the X axis. By default, LO Calc handles them automagically, but you can change them manually. To do so:

1. **Open the "`Chart edit`" mode** - either by double-clicking on the chart, or by single-clicking it and selecting "`Edit`" from the context menu. In chart edit mode, the chart is surrounded by a gray border.
2. Move the cursor over the X Axis until a Popup "`X Axis`" appears; then **select the X axis** with a single left click:

   [image]
3. LO Calc will **display the chart object that's currently selected** by showing little green squares. After selecting the X axis, this should look similar to this:

   [image]
4. With the X axis selected, right-click to open the context menu and **select "`Format Axis...`"**:

   [image]
5. In the following dialogue, **you can modify the Scale attributes**. If you want to modify the settings, you will first have to disable the "`automatic`" checkboxes. Now, you can set e.g. the scale interval to a different value.

   [image]

LO Calc will **adapt the chart accordingly**. Here's the result of manually reducing the major interval:

[image]